# Stored Procedure Syntax Error near 'decimal(10,2)'

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following stored procedure that generates a syntax error:

```
SELECT     
    tbl_ReceiptMaster.receiptMasterId AS ID, 
      date_format(tbl_ReceiptMaster.date,'%d %m %y')  AS Date, 
    tbl_AccountLedger.acccountLedgerName AS 'Ledger ', 
    tbl_ReceiptMaster.receiptMode AS 'Receipt Mode', 
    tbl_ReceiptMaster.description AS Description,
   cast( tbl_ReceiptDetails.amount as decimal(18,2))as amount
FROM         tbl_ReceiptMaster 
INNER JOIN tbl_ReceiptDetails ON tbl_ReceiptMaster.receiptMasterId = tbl_ReceiptDetails.receiptMasterId 
INNER JOIN   tbl_AccountLedger ON tbl_ReceiptDetails.ledgerId = tbl_AccountLedger.ledgerId
 order by  cast (tbl_ReceiptMaster.receiptMasterId as decimal(10,2)) desc ;
```

Here is the error:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that 
corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 
'decimal(10,2)) desc' at line 11
```

How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an alias `amount` instead of expression `cast( tbl_ReceiptDetails.amount as decimal(18,2))` in order by clause, try below solution

```
SELECT tbl_ReceiptMaster.receiptMasterId AS ID, 
       date_format(tbl_ReceiptMaster.date,'%d %m %y')  AS Date, 
        tbl_AccountLedger.acccountLedgerName AS 'Ledger ', 
        tbl_ReceiptMaster.receiptMode AS 'Receipt Mode', 
        tbl_ReceiptMaster.description AS Description,
       cast( tbl_ReceiptDetails.amount as decimal(18,2))as amount
FROM         tbl_ReceiptMaster 
INNER JOIN tbl_ReceiptDetails ON tbl_ReceiptMaster.receiptMasterId = tbl_ReceiptDetails.receiptMasterId 
INNER JOIN   tbl_AccountLedger ON tbl_ReceiptDetails.ledgerId = tbl_AccountLedger.ledgerId
order by  amount desc ;
```